# Reading an excel file with c++ (General direction)

Tags: c++, excel

I'm new to C++ and I was told to do a project to maintain my scholarship in school for another year.
They're dumped this on me and I was watching 'Bucky' on YouTube to learn C++
He helped... not that much though. 
I need to submit this in a week to maintain my scholarship. Please help?
Here is the gist of the question.

I need to create my own vector. I have an excel document from which information would be read: the document looks like this;

Course Of Sales

```
Time              Price ($) Volume   Value ($)  Condition

10/10/2013 16:57    5.81    5000    29050       LT XT

10/10/2013 16:48    5.81    62728   364449.68   SX XT

10/10/2013 16:10    0       0       0
```

I figured I needed the following classes:

> 1 - Date class
>
> 2 - Time class
>
> 3 - Stock class
>
> 4 - Vector class

I don't know where to start, how to start. I'm getting the jitters.
Any help or guidance? That would be great. Really.
I have a week to do this... Please.

Comment: we're not here to do your homework, what do you know about classes? Do you know how to import data from excel?

Answer (score 0):

So I would do these steps.
Open file using the ifstream.
Once the file is open, read in the data using the

```
std::ifstream inData;
inData.open("inventory.txt");

while(!inData.eof())
{

}
```

Use string stream and strings to hold the data as such. (Inside the while loop)

```
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::string token;

    //declare YOUR values you need
    unsigned id;
    std::string name;
    double price;

    if (getline(ss, token, '|') && std::stringstream(token) >> id)
    {
        if (getline(ss, name, '|'))
            {
                if (getline(ss, token, '|') && std::stringstream(token) >> price)
                {


            }
        }
    }
```

Splitting it up is determined with whatever character is in the single quotes. ('') As my file data is such

```
2386|meadow gold table cream|2.49
```

You simply can read in the file by having it space delimited. As have just a space in the single quotes. (' ')
By using vectors you have a easy way to give it to the class where you can manage the data. That part should be rather easy to figure out so with the example and some sort of a rough plan I'm sure you can figure it out. Once you have the data read in you should be golden and be able to figure it out. Good Luck!